# How to localize "Touch ID for" text

Tags: ios, swift

Anyone know how to localize "Touch ID for" text in `LAContext` class.

[image: IDenter image description here]

Comment: The title is already localized by the system. It's different depending on device language.

Comment: it doesn't localize the text for me unless It failed to log in using Touch ID

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsfaceidusagedescription ?